# Redirect omitting parameters in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, server

After a couple of hours of fighting, I manage to generate an htacces file to redirect all my old URLs to the URLs of my new site (same domain). I am using the following rules to manage my subfolders redirects (my new site has only a couple of pages):

```
RewriteRule ^es/empresa/terminos-y-condiciones.html$ http://domain/terminos-y-condiciones.html [L]
RewriteRule ^es/servicios/registro-de-dominios/.*$ http://domain/dominios.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^es/empresa/.*$ http://domain/nosotros.html [R=301,NC,L]   
RewriteRule ^es/component/.*$ http://domain/contacto.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^es(/.*)?$ / [R=301,NC,L]
```

The problem is that when I try to access to some pages like domain.com/empresa/testimonios-de-clientesc69a.html?lang=es it redirects me to domain/?lang=es , that is my domain+the parameter after ".html".

So, I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate this parameter and redirect only to www.domain.com ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To truncate a query string add a '?' sign to the end of target URLs like this:

```
RewriteRule ^es/empresa/.*$ http://domain/nosotros.html? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

On Apache 2.4 or later you can use the `QSD` flag to discard the query string ([see documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd)):

> When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI
>   does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query
>   string to the target URI. Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string
>   to be discarded.

So it would look like

```
RewriteRule ^es/empresa/.*$ http://domain/nosotros.html [R=301,NC,L,QSD]
```